# Deleting a Kinetic.Node : remove() or destroy()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have an MVC application I'm using KineticJS in one of my views. I want to know what method is better to use if I am deleting a shape or image from a group and eventually from the database. Would it be `destroy()` or `remove()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With remove, you can remove a node from the canvas but you are able to use it later again if you want.
With destroy the node is completely destroyed and can't be reused.

So, if you want to delete an element completely, use destroy, otherwise use remove.

Comment: So you're saying that destroy() is better in my case?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use it again later, it's better to use destroy.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I just want to know how can someone practically use a removed node?

Answer (score 1):

This is the source code below.... destroy() looks like it calls remove() doesn't it? So basically they are redundant?

```
remove: function () {
    var c = this.getParent();
    return c && c.children && (c.children.splice(this.index, 1), c._setChildrenIndices(), delete this.parent), this._clearSelfAndDescendantCache(q), this._clearSelfAndDescendantCache(b), this._clearSelfAndDescendantCache(t), this._clearSelfAndDescendantCache(j), this._clearSelfAndDescendantCache(a), this
},
destroy: function () {
    Kinetic._removeId(this.getId()), Kinetic._removeName(this.getName(), this._id), this.remove()
},
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand this code completely any way. But you've got a point. I hope someone will explain.